# Sitecore Virtual User - user profile deletion

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am trying to login with a virtual user created like in the following:

```
var virtualUser = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(emailAddress, true);
```

and log in like in the following:

```
AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser);
```

The user that I am trying to use as a virtual user, already exists in Sitecore (trying to implement an impersonation feature).

Now, the problem that I have here, is that after login, all the user information from the initial user profile gets deleted. Does anyone know why this happens and how could I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: The version is Sitecore 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

I finally got the answer for this.

Between building a virtual user and logging in, I had to the the following steps in order to keep the profile:

```
SetBaseProfile();
SaveUserRoles();                       
virtualUser.Profile.Save();
```

Of course these here are for my own needs, but the main idea was that had to set all necessary things on the profile, even if I already had profile properties for the virtual user (user already existed in `Sitecore`)

Thanks.